# How to replace duplicate keys in a map

Tags: scala, dictionary

HI I am fairly new to scala programming.
I want to know is there a way to rename the duplicate keys of map.

Suppose if I have a scala map here like

("a"->1,"b"->2,"c"->3,"d"->4,"a"->5,"c"->6,"e"->7,"a"->8)

I want the output in below format.The map should look like

("a_1"->1,"b"->2,"c_1"->3,"d"->4,"a_2"->5,"c_2"->6,"e"->7,"a_3"->8)

I just want to kind of assign a count system for each duplicate key occurrance.

So far I have been able to write a code which will give the no of occurance for a duplicate key.

```
var seq=map.toSeq
var cnt=seq.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.length)`
```

Comment: It is kind of curios that values are ascending, is the original data just `List("a", "b", ..., "a")`?

Comment: The actual data is like this                                                 
(items_id,1001)
(items_type,Regular)
(items_id,1002)
(items_type,Chocolate)
(items_id,1003)
(items_type,Blueberry)
(items_id,1004)
(items_type,Devil's Food)

Comment: It feels like you really want to do a more robust parsing. Because it seems that the values are of different types and I have the impression that you want to add that idx to the keys because you latter want to do something like `val id = map(s"items_id_${i}").toInt` - I would recommend you to edit your question and include all your problem.

Comment: I think  @baitmbarek has the right answer..I just need to change the condition little bit

Comment: Yes his / her answer is probably what you want for what you asked. What I mean is that in general, it seems you are using an unsafe approach to your problem.

Comment: @Luis I will try to edit the question to make it understandble

Comment: A `Map` can't have duplicate keys to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
val seq = Seq("a"->1,"b"->2,"c"->3,"d"->4,"a"->5,"c"->6,"e"->7,"a"->8)

val cnt = seq.groupBy(_._1).flatMap{case (_, elems) => elems.zipWithIndex.map{case ((k,v), i) => s"${k}_${i+1}" -> v}}
print(cnt)
```

Output :

```
Map(c_1 -> 3, d_1 -> 4, a_2 -> 5, b_1 -> 2, a_3 -> 8, c_2 -> 6, a_1 -> 1, e_1 -> 7)
```

Note : if "`b_1`" should be formatted as "`b`", you can introduce a condition based on `elems` size

Edit :

Here's the code :

```
val cnt = seq.groupBy(_._1).flatMap{case (_, elems) => if(elems.size>1){ elems.zipWithIndex.map{case ((k,v), i) => s"${k}_${i+1}" -> v}} else elems}
println(cnt)
Map(e -> 7, c_1 -> 3, a_2 -> 5, b -> 2, a_3 -> 8, c_2 -> 6, a_1 -> 1, d -> 4)
```

Comment: Like this ??                                                                                                                                                                                                                                val val cnt = seq.groupBy(_._1).flatMap{case (_, elems) => 

if(elems.size>1){
elems.zipWithIndex.map{case ((k,v), i) => s"${k}_${i+1}" -> v}}
}
print(cnt)